Title: How to Skip Loading Duplicate CSS Files in Nimbus Bundle Loader?
I am currently facing an issue where my app, loaded in the Nimbus Bundle Loader, is loading two CSS files (main.css and chunk.css) with the same content. I want to find a solution to skip loading one of these files without causing any adverse effects.
The specific behavior I am observing is that main.css is being appended to the shadow root, while chunk.css is being appended to the head during the Webpack runtime.
I would appreciate any suggestions or best practices on how to handle this situation effectively. The goal is to eliminate the duplicate CSS file loading while ensuring the app functions as intended.
Initially, I attempted to skip loading main.css, but this caused issues with the CSS styles not being applied correctly since it was appended to the shadow root.
To address this, I tried appending chunk.css to the shadow root instead. However, I encountered a challenge in finding the instance of the shadow root to perform the append operation. As a workaround, I appended chunk.css to the body with a specific ID and later attempted to attach it to the shadow root using that ID. Unfortunately, this approach resulted in both files being loaded, leading to duplicate styles.
I also considered skipping chunk.css, but I discovered that it is by default appended to the head, and I am unsure if it can be safely skipped without causing any issues.
I am seeking guidance on the best approach to handle this situation effectively. My goal is to avoid loading duplicate CSS files while ensuring that the styles are applied correctly within the app.
